# Ray runtimes and task placement on hardware

Tags: python, opencv, ray

I am completely new to Ray and am trying to understand runtimes. I want to execute YOLO object detector from OpenCV. I wrote the following code to benchmark performance:

```
@ray.remote
def f(x):
    a, b, c = cv.detect_common_objects(x)

# reading in frame etc. omitted
# num_runs is the number of benchmarking runs 
# num_parallel is the number of parallel OpenCV function calls in Ray


ray.init(num_cpus=min(16, num_parallel))

# run with Ray in parallel
for j in range(num_runs):

    start = time.time()

    result_ids = []
    for i in range(num_parallel):
        result_ids.append(f.remote(frame))
    results = ray.get(result_ids)

    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)

# benchmark without Ray: Sequentially call OpenCV function
for j in range(num_runs):

    start_noray = time.time()
    
    for i in range(num_parallel):
        a, b, c = cv.detect_common_objects(frame)

    end_noray = time.time()
    print(end_noray-start_noray)
```

I'm running on a 16 core CPU. After warm up, the runtimes look as follows:

| `num_parallel` | Ray | No ray, sequential |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1900ms | 350ms |
| 8 | 2000ms | 2900s |
| 16 | 4000ms | 6000ms |

If I run `top` in another shell, it tells me that Ray is using 100% of the CPU in all 3 cases (also when `num_parallel = 1`). I am trying to understand these runtimes now:

The OpenCV function allows for parallel execution. The only explanation I can find for these runtimes is that each Ray worker is always placed on 2 CPU cores. But shouldn't the CPU utilization in `top` be lower then? Also, is there a way how a worker is placed on more CPU cores like it is the case when just calling the function without using Ray?

PS: I also ommited the `num_cpus=min(16, num_parallel)` in `ray.init()` and this didn't cahnge the runtimes. I have it now to make sure idle ray processes don't push up the CPU utilization.

Comment: OpenCV already appears to use all cores. you will gain nothing, and lose time to the extra coordination effort.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that 1.5s can't be explained by just coordination overhead in the case of num_parallel=1. Also, why would num_parallel=1 and num_parallel=8 have the same runtime then?